# ambiguous column name error sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I have written the following Procedure to display the results as pivot as per the requirement

```
DECLARE @values AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @values = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + ColumnName + ']'
        FROM xTable 
        FOR xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'') 

SET @query = 'SELECT viewName1.*, pValues.Code, ' + @values + ' FROM 
             (
              SELECT Column1,Column2, Column3
                FROM viewname

            ) aliasName
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(value)
                FOR ColumnName in (' + @values + ')
            ) pValues  INNER JOIN viewName1 ON pValues.Code = viewname.Code'
   EXEC(@query)
```

But when the value and column names are same in my `xTable and viewName1` I am getting that error how can I resolve this. I tried with alas but I am not getting the expected result so can some one help me.

Sample is I am having a `ColumnName` as `TopBrand` in my table `xTable`, this can be a value in my `viewName1` like for `X` Column `TopBrand` can be a value.

Comment: You are getting an ambiguous column name, because 2 of your tables have a column named the same, and SQL does not know which one to pick. Maybe aliasing your tables, and accessing columns from your alias would work?

Comment: Hi not columns names when I am using `PIVOT` to convert values to column names I am getting the `issue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a separate list for `FOR` and `IN` clauses and the former should include the alias:

```
DECLARE @valuesFor AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @valuesIn AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @valuesFor = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT N',pValues.[' + ColumnName + ']'
        FROM xTable 
        FOR xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'') 

SELECT @valuesIn = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT N',[' + ColumnName + ']'
        FROM xTable 
        FOR xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'') 

SET @query = N'SELECT viewName1.*, pValues.Code, ' + @valuesFor + N' FROM 
             (
              SELECT Column1,Column2, Column3
                FROM viewname

            ) aliasName
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(value)
                FOR ColumnName in (' + @valuesIn + N')
            ) pValues  INNER JOIN viewName1 ON pValues.Code = viewname.Code'
   EXEC(@query)
```